# Microsoft AdMediation Control crashes

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I use the AdMediation Control (v 2.0) from Microsoft for my Windows 8.1 Store Application. I added "Microsoft Advertising" via "Connected Service...".
I added the Id and the Name to the `AdMediatorControl` and configured the "Connected Service".
When I now start my application and the ad should load, I get this error, after I enabled native Debugging in the Project:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD4E38A1C8 in ClientWindowsUI.Windows.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x000000FF7D4FF070. HRESULT:0x80070002 The System cannot find the mentioned file
>
> WinRT information: The System cannot find the mentioned file
>
> Stack trace:
>   [External Code]
>   UniversalXamlAdControl.Windows.dll!00007ffd0d292b96()
>   UniversalXamlAdControl.Windows.dll!00007ffd0d2d43d1()
>   [External Code]
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Remark to quote: I translated the German Message "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" to "The System cannot find the mentioned file"

Has anybody an idea what can be the Problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Apparently, running the solution in Release instead of Debug solved the problem. Not great, but it works for now.

Comment: My problem was, that there was something wrong in my obj- and bin-folder. I removed all AdMediator related things from my Projects as well as that package.xml-file in my project. Then I deleted the bin- and obj folder and finally rebuilded everything and added the AdMediator again. Also keep in mind, that the "Any"-CPU-Configuration is not supported by the AdMediaton Control. You must run x86 or x64 or ARM